# Is harmonic oscillator a free particle in disguise?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, integrable-systems

Let me start with an example. If one considers a free particle motion on two-dimensional plane and projects it onto the radial coordinate, one gets the following Hamiltonian
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2}+g^2 \frac{1}{ q^2}$$
which is integrable (and known as a one-particle rational Calogero model). Considering free motions on sphere and other (homogeneous) spaces, one is able to discover different integrable systems.

Hence follows my question: does harmonic oscillator (and its generalizations to multiparticle case) represent a free motion on some space?

In my naïveté I thought about a space with metric of the form $ds^2 = dr^2 + \dfrac{d\theta^2}{r^2}$, but this is not, of course, a space of constant curvature, and moreover, its Ricci scalar diverges as $R = -\frac{4}{r^2}$ at $r=0$. Of course, in one-particle case it doesn't matter since all systems of searched form are such, but it might matter later.

Comment: Your radial metric at the end isn't dimensionally consistent, it should be $r^2 d\theta^2$ no?

Comment: @Triatticus yes, it may seem dimensionally inconsistent indeed, but that probably doesn't matter: first of all, I don't claim that \theta are indeed the angle and radial coordinates (they could both have no dimensions and just have a common dimensionfull parameter in front of them, just as the metric on sphere ds^2=a^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)), and secondly, I completely agree that what is written is probably wrong, but, then, if I knew the answer I probably wouldn't have asked the question :)

Comment: @Triatticus as for dr^2+ r^2 d\theta, it is just the metric on plane in polar coordinates. It leads to free particle Lagrangian L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dor{\theta}^2), which turns into Hamiltonian H =1/2( p_r^2 + p_\theta^2/r^2), and is exactly the source of the first formula in the question